# Python Game Help: How to have a function always remain true once true.

Tags: python, function

I am making a python game and am having a quick little issue. There is a hallway that splits left and right. When you go left, there is a key you obtain and when you go right there is a locked elevator. The key is what you need to unlock the elevator. The issue arises when a user tries to go backward in a game and they re-arrive at the hall. Code below:

```
def elevator(Lock):
    if lock== 'unlock':
        print "Unlocked"

    else:
        print "It is locked"

def safe():
    print "obtain key"
    right_left('True')

def right_left(Key):
    backward = ['back']
    left = ['left', 'Left']
    right = ['right', 'Right']
    choice = raw_input("Enter Command > ")

    if Key == 'True':
        print "Left or right?"

        if choice== 'right':
            elevator('Unlock')
        elif choice == 'back':
            back()

    else:
        if any (s in choice for s in backward):
            back()

        elif any (s in choice for s in left):
            safe()

        elif any (s in choice for s in right):
            elevator()

def back():
    print "Back in the game."
    right_left('False')
```

The big issue I am having is that if a user picks up the key and goes back to the left right hall and then they choose to go back. If they go back in the game and go all the way back to the beginning (Which is not in this sample/example) it will go back the 'back()' function and continue to the 'right_left' function with Key = false. But it needs to be true. I cannot figure out how once 'right_left' is true, it will always be true regardless of whatever a user does in the future. Thanks and sorry this is confusing

Comment: `if Key == 'True':`... ow ow ow ow ow.

Comment: The issue is I do not know how to permanently make it Key=='True' in the back() function. If a user kept going back in a game and came back to that bacl() function, how can I make it so it will be Key=='True'. That is what I am struggling with. How do you tell if the user has or hasn't picked up the key?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ `Key` remain "True" forever? It would only change value if you're explicitly changing it yourself. If you want Key to be "True", just don't make it not "True".

Comment: My pain is from using a *string* containing the *word* `True` instead of using `True` for Boolean values... and then writing out the whole condition instead of just doing `if key`.... ow ow.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a bad design to write a text adventure by having each room be a different function, and having each room call the room you're moving into. Most versions of Python have a maximum recursion depth of 1000, so your game will crash when you try to move from one room to another for the 999th time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your structure is calling itself on an endless stack of right_left() calls, which seems to have no way of escaping.  You're only passing two different strings ('True', 'False') into this method, so there is no real state of the user.

You need to do a major restructuring of the paths for the user, and separate the move decision from the room logic.  Then you can hold some kind of context for the user, and possibly some state for the rooms.  This would benefit from a object-oriented design, otherwise you will need to use globals to keep state of rooms.

To do this with global variables, you may define some methods like:

```
# global variable to keep track
rooms=['safe', 'closet','main']
currentRoom=rooms[0]

# returns which the new room you are in.
def move(fromRoom, direction): 

# main section
while (response != "exit"):
   choice = raw_input("Enter Command > ")
   move(currentRoom, choice)

# etc..
```

Comment: Sorry but could you give a quick example of this with sample functions. I am having trouble grasping how to do this. Sorry I am not as knowledgeable as the others on this site lol. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good problem for Object oriented code.  See below for a quick example.  First you might want to create a gameState Object as follows:

```
class gameState(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.hasKey = False

   def pickUpKey(self):
      self.hasKey = True

   def hasKey(self):
      return self.hasKey
```

This game state object can also than be used to house more information about yoru game, like current location for example.

You will then want to create an instance of the gameState Object ( to be passed to each function or used as a global variable ).  For example your main may look like:

```
def main():
    currentState = gameState()
    main_game_loop( currentState )
```